# How to change all numbers by a % in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Sorry I am still a beginner but slowly getting there. I want to change all the "base-purchase-prices" by a % all at once? I am tearing my hair out trying to work out how to do it. There are 7000 line items so simply saying "get a calculator" is not going to work

```json
{ 
  "tradeable-code": "Scissors_01", 
  "base-purchase-price": "110", 
  "base-sell-price": "12", 
  "delta-price": "-1.0", 
  "can-be-purchased":"default" 
},
{ 
  "tradeable-code": "Scissors_Plastic", 
  "base-purchase-price": "88", 
  "base-sell-price": "9", 
  "delta-price": "-1.0", 
  "can-be-purchased":"default" 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

- select all the `base-purchase-price` prices

  - perform a regex find with: `(?<="base-purchase-price": ")([^"]*)`
  - press `Alt+Enter` while focus in Find dialog
- Execute command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression (regex)**
- for **Match Original Text Regular Expression** enter: `(.*)`
- for **Generator Regular Expression** enter: `{{=N[1]*1.05:fixed(2):simplify}}`
- this increases the prices with 5% (1+0.05) and rounds it to 2 decimal digits
- if you like the preview type `Enter` otherwise `Esc`
- press `Esc` to leave Multi Cursor Mode

Comment: HI RioV8, It is just a language file (not a program) that I have opened in Visual Studio Code to edit.  It then gets uploaded to a server as a json

Comment: @Dean A text file is a text file, program or not, it has some structure we can use to find/replace

Answer (score 0):

Using this extension: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform), full disclosure - written by me, it is easy to do math on any values in your file.

For example, make this keybinding, in your `keybindings.json` file (it could also be made into a setting that will become a command in the Command Palette if you want:

```
{
  "key": "alt+c",                    // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(?<=base-purchase-price\":\\s*\")(\\d+)",
    "isRegex": true,
    "replace": [
      "$${",
        
        "return ($1 * 1.05).toFixed(2);", 

      "}$$"
    ]
  }
```

The `find` will capture only the digits you want to change.  The `replace` will run any math (or string) operation you want.  Here I simply multiplied the capture group `$1` by 1.05 and set it to 2 decimal places.

[image: capture and change a value by a percentage]